# How can I play Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2

Tags: 11.10, games

I want to play cod:mw2 but I don't know how to get it on Ubuntu. I am a new user so explanation would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can play it through wine

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=18348

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1325021